# Serve images using express or send binary data to client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm not sure about best practices to go about displaying images stored in MongoDB database.

I have a user uploading an image through React then that is sent to an express server via an API call. Then I use multer to get the buffer data and send that to MongoDB.

Currently, to display an image on the front-end I use express to serve up the image. Meaning I can access any image in mongo by typing 'http://localhost:3000/api/image/*image_id*

With that being said in the front end. I have an API call which grabs all the images Ids and then use them to create a link. Something like this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        imgID: ''
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <img src={"http://localhost:3000/api/image/" + this.state.imgID} />
     )
}
```

My question is if this is a good practice or should I send the client the binary data and render it on their end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to serve the image by providing the URL instead of sending binary data

**Reason:**

- If you send binary data it will take more bandwidth so it takes more time to get the image
- When you send the binary data, the user, at the front end has to specify it in  `<img>` tag that it should expect binary data like this

```html
<img src="data:image/<format of the image>;base64, <actual base64 string>" alt="alternate" />.
```

Comment: So the way I am approaching it right now would be best?